# Query List of nested Viewmodels

Tags: vb.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I have the following nested viewmodels:

```
Public Class ContentViewModel
    Public Property CONTENTID As Integer
    Public Property IMAGETOCONTENT() As IEnumerable(Of ImageToContentViewModel)
End Class

Public Class ImageToContentViewModel
    Public Property IMAGETOCONTENTID As Integer
    Public Property IMAGE As ImageViewModel
End Class

Public Class ImageViewModel
    Public Property IMAGEID As Integer
    Public Property TITLE As String
End Class
```

I'm trying to query the nested viewmodels:

```
Function Test() As ContentViewModel
    Dim dataObject = (From a In db.CMS_CONTENT.OfType(Of CMS_EVENT)()
                 Where a.CONTENTID = contentId AndAlso a.DELETED = 0
                 Select New ContentViewModel With {
                     .CONTENTID = a.CONTENTID,                        
                     .IMAGETOCONTENT = (From b In db.CMS_IMAGES_TO_CONTENT
                      Where b.CONTENTID = a.CONTENTID
                      Select New ImageToContentViewModel With {
                          .IMAGETOCONTENTID = b.IMAGETOCONTENTID,
                          .IMAGE = (From c In db.CMS_IMAGES
                                    Where c.IMAGEID = b.IMAGEID And c.DELETED = False
                                    Select New ImageViewModel With {
                                        .IMAGEID = c.IMAGEID,
                                        .TITLE = c.TITLE
                                    })
                      })
                 })

    Return dataObject 
End Function
```

My Problem is that I can't return the populated viewmodel, because I always get the Error:

The object of Type "System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[MvcApp.ContentViewModel]" cannot be converted to "MvcApp.ContentViewModel"

Answer (score 0):

Your function body creates an `IQueryable` of `ContentViewModel` (implemented as `` System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[MvcApp.ContentViewModel] ``), because that is what the `Select` returns.

You either should use `FirstOrDefault()`, or change the return type into `IQueryable` (of `ContentViewModel`).

Comment: If I use `Return dataObject.FirstOrDefault()` I get _Type 'System.Linq.IQueryable1' can not be converted to type 'MvcApp.ImageViewModel'. 'LINQ to Entities' only supports the conversion of primitive Entity Data Model Types_ and if I use `IQueryable (of ContentViewModel)` as return type the query executes but how would I get the result into a single viewmodel `Dim viewModel = New EventViewModel`?

Comment: You must use FirstOrDefault after each Select, also the nested ones. But then you must be aware that the linq queries may return lists with more than one item. Do you really always need the first one only?

Comment: Actually the parent viewmodel ContentViewModel(single) has a nested List of ImageToContentViewModel(ienumerable) and each ImageToContentViewModel has a nested ImageViewModel(single).

Comment: OK, so no FirstOrDefault on `ContentViewModel.IMAGETOCONTENT`.

Comment: As soon as I put the FirstOrDefault on the outer query (EventViewModel) I get the primitive type excepion.

Comment: I ended up separating the outer query and the inner two queries (joined the two tables) to populate the viewmodel. Works quite nice now. Thanks for your help @Gernot Arnod